# Expo BackgroundFetch not executing

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to run some code on a set interval in the background of my Expo app.

I've tried using the solution here: https://snack.expo.io/B1G39XcZr, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm currently just trying to get a console.log working.

```
BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(60);
const taskName = 'test-background-fetch';

TaskManager.defineTask(taskName, () => {
  console.log('task run')
  return BackgroundFetch.Result.NewData;
});
```

...

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.registerTaskAsync();
}

registerTaskAsync = async () => {
  await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(taskName);
  console.log('task registered');
};
```

'task registered' gets printed, but 'task run' is never printed.